# Web applications have "the todo list." What analogous program is there for systems programming?

Tags: systems-programming, analogy

You can find [many frameworks](http://todomvc.com/) with an example todo list for demonstrating a small but full application in the framework.  You don't have to consider large problems like scaling or caching, but you still exercise most of the fundamentals of that framework in a todo list.

Is there an analogous application for [systems-level programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_programming)?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the "TodoMVC" site. Great resource!

Answer (score 2):

Not a single one, but different areas of computing have traditions. For writing network services, the canonical functional-though-useless example is to write an echo server (it listens on a port and parrots back everything it hears). The simplest command-line utility imaginable is one that simply returns a specific exit code ([Here](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) is an astounding example of just how simple it can be made to be) - it does virtually nothing, but can still be helpful to introduce someone to the code-compile-link-execute cycle. If you count programming languages and libraries, of course there's always "Hello, world!", and almost every language has its perceived weaknesses that everyone tries to fix. For C++, it's writing a better `string` type;  of Perl, it is jokingly said, that every serious user has tried their hand at a better option-parsing library.

Comment: I feel like the relative complexity between "hello world" and a todo list in a web framework is much greater than the relative complexity from "hello world" and `exit($ARGV[0].to_i)` in a systems level language (C, C++, Go, etc.).  But +1 for the echo server example.